# SOAP empty envelope. How to handle empty responses

Tags: php, soap, error-handling

I am working for a while now with the SOAP API (self teached during work projects). But one thing always bothers me, is that I can't figure out how to handle an empty response.

For instance: I call the service to get some articles from an ERP system. The input parameter is the article number or the GTIN.

Here is some sample code: https://codeshare.io/5e3EYr

If for instance no GTIN is set (just for understanding) the response is not an array anymore (single or multidimensional). The return would be a soap error like "Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array" Because the return is the error message.

I hope you understand my problem. I already tried to check if it is_array and even tried to catch the string. But I always get the "Fatal error: Cannot use string offset..." message.

Comment: I would suggest using a shutdown handler to catch fatal errors like that. see PHP Docs  http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php

Comment: hmm, I think that's not what I am looking for. As I understand it, such a function can be executed after the script finsihes. As last action. I think I miss just one basic understanding of SOAP.

Comment: no, once you get a fatal error php stops executing the script, the only way to return anything after that is to "somehow" catch the error and then do something with the error information. (such as output a return to the client).  I has nothing to do with SOAP and everything to do with how errors are handled.

Comment: Just to explain, if you know how to use `try` `catch` for exceptions its basically the same idea, except try/catch doesn't work on "error" so you have to use one of the 2 error handlers that can catch them.  But just like execution stops for an exception it stops on fatal errors and basically gets kicked out of our script where the error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Something like ( as an example for my comment )

```
function handleShutdown(){

   $lasterror = error_get_last();

    if (is_null($lasterror)) {
       //normal shutdown 
        return false;
    }

    //return error to client as XML, JSON etc.
    // $lasterror['message']
    // $lasterror['type']
    // $lasterror['file']
    // $lasterror['line']
}

register_shutdown_function('handleShutdown');
```

I will leave it up to you on how you want to format the error message.  The shutdown handler can even catch out of memory errors ... :)

Obviously, you cant catch anything before it's registered so do it early in execution.

php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php

You may also want to look at

- set_error_handler
- set_exception_handler

Then you can have the trifecta of error handling.

You could use set_error_handler to catch these but you would want to filter out errors of certain verities (in the error handler), an example would be Deprecated or Notice level errors.  You can do this with checking the Severity against the `error_reporting` level you have (bitwise) like this

```
if($severity & error_reporting()) 
   //report on these errors.
```

Notice the single & is a bitwise comparison and differs from the normal AND (&&)

**Now** if you want to prevent the error altogether, I would need to see the code (including the line - marked somehow) where it is produced.  Otherwise it's just wild guessing.

In any case when building some kind of service that lacks the normal GUI, it never hurts to have shutdown recovery to send feedback to the client, just make sure to sanitize any output information you share with clients.  That way you don't "leak" information that may give away any information that could be used to compromise your application.

cheers.

Comment: As I just read my question again, I figured it out. My starting point was always to check if an array is returned. That was right, but I checked the wrong line. In my example code, I have to check the SOAP envelope if there is a [row] and so it would be an array. But your answer helped me a lot in understanding error handling. As I did not know that try and catch does not work with errors ;) Thanks!

Comment: Sure I still recommend using some error recovery stuff as with no GUI for API type stuff, there is no way to give feedback to the clients that something went wrong.  I would just keep the errors somewhat generic as security precaution.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured out, which part to check for an array. If it is not an array, nothing happens. And if, everything is fine.

```
if(is_array(['getSomeArticleResult']['SqlRowSet']['diffgram']['SqlRowSet1'])){
$aSuppl = $aSuppl['getSomeArticleResult']['SqlRowSet']['diffgram']['SqlRowSet1']['row'];
return $aSuppl;
}
```

Comment: you could just use `!empty()`